# lost after upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I just upgraded from version 10.04 to 12.04.
The interface is so different I am lost. In particular, after exploring I noticed that Eclipse and Netbeans were still installed, but I dont know how to run them.
Same goes for the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the dashboard (the icon in the upper left corner of the launcher with the ubuntu logo) and type the name of the application you want to run there. When it is found it will show you the application's icon. You can start it directly by clicking on it or drag the icon to the launcher to have in there permanently.